# JavaScript: Store a playlist in-memory

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store a playlist of songs in my application. What's the most flexible and efficient way to do this? Each song has a few fields, like: song_name, song_id, song_artist etc. The playlist is sent to the client as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Dustin Dias has a nice cache script that stores the values as json either as an simple javascript object variable or in window.localStorage:

http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-cache-provider/